# Correct way to move artifacts between workflow runs

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-api

Context: I'm trying to upload an artifact on merge of a PR and attempting to fetch the artifact on all new pull requests  in order to do some comparison with the uploaded artifact.

Github provides the upload-artifact and download-artifact actions to upload and download artifacts between jobs within the same workflow. The download-artifact  is limited to the current workflow and as such is not of use when we want to download artifacts saved in the merge workflow.

There is a third party action https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact that was made for this exact use case. However I have been trying to get it to work and I keep running into no artifacts found error, which is what it mean, the action is unable to find the artifact that I'm asking it to search for.

I have tried to see if the artifact is downloadable in the same workflow, download-artifact  works fine when trying to fetch an artifact in the same workflow, dawidd6/action-download-artifact however still throws the same not found error. I have tried making the search as specific as possible and making it as broad as possible with no luck.

Below is a simplified implementation of just the upload and download workflows

`UploadArtifact.yml`

```
name: upload artifact on push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  Sha: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
      

jobs:
  update-benchmark-result:
    name: Update latest benchmark result
    needs: benchmark
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Update benchmark result
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: Artifact_${{ env.Sha }}
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/results.json
```

and the artifact gets uploaded perfectly well, I can even see it on the UI.

```
Artifact name is valid!
Container for artifact "benchmark-result_98945f28b7772329f07f3166cf865e651931042b" successfully created. Starting upload of file(s)
Total size of all the files uploaded is 1167 bytes
File upload process has finished. Finalizing the artifact upload
Artifact has been finalized. All files have been successfully uploaded!

The raw size of all the files that were specified for upload is 9411 bytes
The size of all the files that were uploaded is 1167 bytes. This takes into account any gzip compression used to reduce the upload size, time and storage

Note: The size of downloaded zips can differ significantly from the reported size. For more information see: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#zipped-artifact-downloads 

Artifact Artifact_98945f28b7772329f07f3166cf865e651931042b has been successfully uploaded!
```

However when I try to download the same artifact in a different workload as shown below, I get this error -

```
with:
    github_token: ***
    event: push
    run_number: 34
    name: Artifact_98945f28b7772329f07f3166cf865e651931042b
    name_is_regexp: false
    if_no_artifact_found: fail
    workflow_conclusion: success
    repo: <repo>/v3.0
    path: ./
    check_artifacts: false
    search_artifacts: false
    skip_unpack: false
==> Repository: <repo>/v3.0
==> Artifact name: Artifact_98945f28b7772329f07f3166cf865e651931042b
==> Local path: ./
==> Workflow name: 64604384
==> Workflow conclusion: success
==> Event: push
==> Run number: 34
Error: no matching workflow run found with any artifacts?
```

`Download.yml`

```
name: Regression test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  Sha: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
      

jobs:
  benchmark:
    name: Run Benchmarks on PR
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          submodules: true
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: '1.18.10'
      - run: echo 'go version  $(go version)'
  update-benchmark-result:
     name: Download artifact
     id: download-artifact
     uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
       with:
          github_token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          event: push
          run_number: 34
          name: Artifact_98945f28b7772329f07f3166cf865e651931042b
          name_is_regexp: true
          if_no_artifact_found: fail
```